# Using action script 3 with flash builder 4.7 when i try to load image of dimension 16000 X 16000, not able to upload

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder

I found below problem in action script 3.

Using action script 3 with flash builder 4.7 when i try to load image of dimension 16000 X 16000 using below code it will CRASH my App and not able to show image.

Image size is 4.6 MB and Image dimension is 16000 X 16000 (Width X Height)

When i try with other image having Dimension 10000 X 3000 (Width X Height) it will work

```
var mapLoader:Loader=new Loader();
var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo=mapLoader.contentLoaderInfo;      

loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void
            {
            var image:Image=new Image();
            image.source=mapLoader.content;
            image.width=image.source.width * 0.6; 
            image.height=image.source.height * 0.6;             
            image.smooth=true; 
            }
            });
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,function(e:IOErrorEvent):void
            {
                //some code
            });         
            mapLoader.load(new URLRequest(mapSrc));
```

Please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: 16000 * 16000 * 4 equals 1GB of ram.... not surprising that crashes... If you are implementing a scrolling map you should do via a tile-based system.

Comment: @SushiHangover, Thanks for help, I am also use path traversal using astar algorithm with this big dimension images, will it work with tile based system? 
Could you please provide us some links like how to apply tile based system?

Comment: There's not that many technologies out there that will not crash when trying to load that. How did you not know that this was a insanely enormously huge image? This was the obvious problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before Flash Player 11, there was a limitation on the size of any loaded image. As of Flash Player 11, this limitation as been removed, and the maximum size is dependent of the operating system.

Considering that Flash internally handle image as bitmaps, your 16000x16000px image requires around 1Gb of RAM by itself. This may be more than what your app is allowed (or even what your system is capable of).

Since you seems to be making an app, I would recommend using a tile system : the full map is cut down in smaller images, that are then placed side-by-side. Using this system, your app can load and show only the required tiles, strongly reducing the memory required, as well as the necessary bandwidth. If you don't want to show blank spaces while the tiles are loading, you can add a lowres image of the full-map under the tiles, so that the user see a blurred version of this section before the app finished loading the corresponding tile and show the highres version.

Comment: @ Aralicia,Thanks for help, I am also use path traversal using astar algorithm with this big dimension images, will it work with tile based system  for desktop application? 
Could you please provide us some links like how to apply tile based system  for desktop application?

Comment: If you are using pathfinding algorithms on your image, you may want to simplify it beforehand. for example, do you A* travers the map pixel per pixel ? If not, maybe the low-res image may be enough. alternativaly, you can have a simplified "pseudo-map" file which isn't an image and can be treated as an array of values. What exactly is the context of your app ?